# Arduino complie ./xxx.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino

I'm new to arduino, I'm supposed to add tinyGPS.h but locally, but where is "locally"

line of code:

```
#include "./TinyGPS.h"                 // Use local version of this library
```

I've tried copy and pasting the tinygps.h in whatever arduino folder I could under the belief ./ is in the root of the working directory.

I expected the code to compile.

Answer (score 0):

It means in the same directory as the source file in which you wrote `#include`.